# Javascript result in date_modify twig

Tags: javascript, laravel, twig

How to insert the result:

```
<script>
var date = new Date();
document.write(date.getTimezoneOffset());
</script>
```

in

```
{{ post.published_at|date_modify("+999 mins")|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

paste instead of 999.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this solution safe (correct)?

1. Passed the value in cookie:

```
<script>
    var now = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*-1);
    document.cookie = "timezoneoffset="+now;
</script>
```

2. Took it to {{ var }}:

```
     function onStart()  { 
                    if(isset($_COOKIE["timezoneoffset"])) {
                            $time = $_COOKIE["timezoneoffset"];
                            }
                            else {
                            $time = 0;
                            }
                    $this['var'] = $time;
                }
```

3. Ajax updated the partial:

```
{{ post.published_at|date_modify("+" ~ var ~ "mins")|date("m/d/Y") }}
```